# How do i install Epson 3050 Printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, epson

ive been trying to install this with tutorials online but ubuntu keeps on saying the software downloaded from epson is not supported

Comment: What software did you download that is not supported?

Comment: I have L3050 printer. I installed drivers from Epson site and it wors well on 20.04.

Comment: i used the drivers from     http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Comment: So, I installed a driver from there a few minutes ago with no problems. Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly did you download, and what is the problem.

Comment: can you please assist the drivers u used @Pilot6

Comment: when i download the installation file i get an errror  "failed to install file:not supported" @Pilot6

Comment: Don't choose to open the file, save it and copy to your user home directory. See the answer. And which file did you download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download a `amd64` `deb` printer driver from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX
2. Copy it to your user home directory.
3. Run in a terminal

   ```
   sudo apt install ./epson*.deb
   ```
4. Go to Settings -> Printers and add a new printer.

Comment: It worked until step 4. When i go to Settings -> Printers and click Add it never finds my printer even though the printer is connected  to the wifi network

Comment: You can ask a question with more details.

Comment: I actually tried to edit the comment straight after to say it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Epson ET2710 Eco Tank printer. I just installed Synaptic, and installed every package with "epson" in its package name. Afterward the scanner and printer work fine. I've had no problems at all. That was my solution.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original poster's question, and you haven't given any detail for how you did what you did. Would be good to edit your answer with a lot more detail.