# Epson ET-4760 install 20.04

Tags: epson, ubuntu-drivers

I followed instructions here:

[Install epson drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237426/how-do-i-install-epson-3050-printer-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Everything seems to work until it is time to print. The printer shows up in printers-local host, but applications,such as libreoffice can't see it.

Comment: Boy do I have egg on my face. t

Comment: As I was saying. Ouch! The problem was failure to plug the USB cable all the way in in the back of the printer.

Comment: Sorry to bump you. I am interested in buying this printer. Is everything working under Ubuntu?