# EPSON printer does not print

Tags: 20.04, printing, epson

I successfully installed Ubuntu OS 20.04 amd 64 and after the installation I continued with other programs.

Today I have tried to install EPSON printer Stylus DX4050 from the original installation CD and it looked good.

The printer is recognized but does not print at all. The only reported problem is plug the cable to the printer. The cables are plugged in.

On the Terminal I listed all usb ports and i can see the printer listed on 001usb.

Previously it worked on Ubuntu OS 18.04 and I did not have any problems with the printer.

What is the problem and how to fix this it?
Why is the printer not printing?

---

I have original installation CD for Epson Stylus DX4050 copied in home directory. After i placed in Terminal the command: `sudo apt install ./epson*.deb` I got this answer:

```
E: Unsupported file ./epson*.deb given on commandline
```

Printer is recognized but does not print at all. Maybe because on the installation CD is SETUP.EXE file for WindowsXP. I finished the installation from the CD but still the printer does not print pages.

The official EPSON web site does not have driver for Ubuntu 20.04 amd 64.

My question is how to fix it?

Comment: this fix is related to a epson 3050 but you should be able to select your model : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237426/how-do-i-install-epson-3050-printer-on-ubuntu-20-04#1237440

Comment: It looks the driver is your issue based on your latest post.  Try this link https://driverscollection.com/?H=Stylus%20DX4050&By=Epson&SS=Linux  Otherwise you are just keep searching if this doesn't work.

Comment: I would also recommend checking your syslogs, see if anything there may relate to the printer error.  If you're interested you can try running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` , then loading the printer and see what gets output to the terminal.  `tail -f` will output to the terminal in real time so you can get an idea of what may be wrong.  You can always post the output as an edit to your question if you have trouble deciphering the output.

Comment: You can also do a search in the community and see if anything might help as well